# Javascript to filter html table on column?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to filter an html table on column values (vertically like MS Excel filter). I thought following code would work. It is failing, can someone help me understand why it is failing?

Error:

> $("tr").each.find is not a function [Break On This Error]
>
> $('tr').each.find('td').eq(coli)(function() {

the header row of the table has diff class applied to it, and body has diff class applied, if it matters...

```
        rowi = this.rowIndex;
        var coli = e.target.cellIndex;
        cellval = $('tr').eq(rowi).find('td').eq(coli).text();

    $("#filterbutton").click(function() {
        var row = new Array();
        $('tr').each.find('td').eq(coli)(function() {
                if ($(this).text() == cellval) {  //  you can add aditional filter criteria... || $(this).text() == 50) {
                    row.push($(this).index());
                }
            });
        $('th,td').each(function() {
            if (($.inArray($(this).index(), row)==-1) && ($(this).index() != '0')){$(this).hide();}
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('tr').each` expects a function to call on each `tr`:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var $cell = $(this).find('td').eq(coli);

    if ($cell.text() == cellval) {
        row.push(this.rowIndex);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('tr').each.find('td').eq(coli)(function() {`

should be:

`$('tr td:eq(' + coli +')').each(function() { ...`

Answer (score 0):

You  are using the wrong syntax here..  Instead of

```
$('tr').each.find('td').eq(coli)(function() {
           if ($(this).text() == cellval) { 
              row.push($(this).index());
           }
   });
```

// Try this

```
$('tr').each.find('td').eq(coli)(function() {
      var $curr = $(this).find('td:eq('+ coli + ')') ; (OR) $(this).find('td').eq(coli) ; 

      if ($curr.text() == cellval) { 
          row.push($(this).index());
      }
   });
```